# How to convert Application.ActiveFormHandle to TForm object in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

We may get `THandle` of active form by `Application.ActiveFormHandle` or by `GetForegroundWindow` when `Application.Active = True`.

But how to get active form object?

Or how to convert `Application.ActiveFormHandle` to object on Delphi?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a window handle and want to get the VCL control to which this handle belongs you can use [`FindControl`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Controls.FindControl).
If you just want to get the active form you can use [`Screen.ActiveForm`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Forms.TScreen.ActiveForm).